# Determine the number of ways to paint the house with no living rooms, sharing the same colors.

Tags: probability, combinations

A house has $10$ rooms - $8$ bedrooms and $2$ living rooms. We want to paint $5$ of them yellow, and the rest of others $3$ red and $2$ purple.

How many possibilities can we can paint the rooms, such that two living rooms don't share the common colors?

Comment: You can approach the problem this way: Determine the total possibilities to color the rooms. Then, subtract that by the number of possibilities, in which two living rooms have the same colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint/Partial Solution:**

If the first living room was painted yellow and the second living room was painted red, we would still need to paint four more yellow rooms, two more red rooms, and two more purple rooms.

Pick which four of the eight bedrooms were painted yellow.  Then pick which two of the remaining four bedrooms were painted red.  The final two rooms will be painted purple.

> This can be accomplished in $\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$ ways.

Now, if instead the first living room was painted yellow but the second living room was painted purple this time...